# You don’t have permission to fork to these organizations:

Tags: github

I have a private repo that I made in my account.  I want to fork this now to start another project.  When I try to fork it says:

```
You don’t have permission to fork to these organizations:
```

And it lists an open source projects organization I contributed some work to.

This project is nothing to do with that organization, why can't I fork it?  I created this repo in first place and have not pushed code to the other org in years.

Comment: Looks like you are forking into your own account. You can fork repo from one account to another account not into the same account. When you click on "fork" of a repo from source account, GitHub asks you to choose the "second" target account to save the fork. May be you are selecting the Open Source Project Organization, so you see the failure.

Comment: I have created a starter app that I want to base other apps on.  How do I fork my own project or its not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; It is not possible to fork your own repo into your own account.

You can fork repo from one account to another account, but not into the same account. When you click on "fork" of a repo from source account, GitHub asks you to choose the "second" target account to save the fork. May be you are selecting the Open Source Project Organization, so you see the failure.

Refer https://github.community/t5/Support-Protips/Alternatives-to-forking-into-the-same-account/ba-p/7428. This page gives few alternate options.

My Suggestion:

Best option is to use a different branch for each app and your master branch holds the "starter app" or vice-versa, keep base app in one branch and main app in master branch. When ever you create a new app, branch out from base app branch and start development.

Answer (score 1):

Update in 2023: GitHub now allows you to fork your own repo.